# How to find first item that satisfies predicate?

Tags: vimscript

`:help index` explains that only exact matches are returned. How would you add a predicate to the search, so that we could find the first element that matches that?

I want to write this:

```
  let i = 0
  let commit = ''
  while i < len(l:state.commits)
    let commit = l:state.commits[i]
    if predicate(commit) then
      break
    fi
    i += 1
  endwhile
```

but much simpler, as:

```
let commit = index(l:state.commits, predicate)
```

Can this be done in vimscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of "functional programming" in VimScript could be implemented by `:h filter()` function. For example,

```
function! FindItem(object, Fn) abort
    return get(filter(copy(a:object), "a:Fn(v:val)"), 0, v:null)
endfunction
```

Alternatively, your `Fn` can accept two arguments `(index, value)` instead of one (and, maybe, even somehow cache "the first successful result" to avoid extra checks). In this case, you can use it directly: `return get(filter(copy(a:object), a:Fn), 0, v:null)`

Also, if your Vim (not in Neovim yet) is modern enough, you may have access to `:h reduce()` function. Then you can write it like this:

```
function! FindItem(object, Fn) abort
    return reduce(a:object, {acc, val -> acc isnot v:null ? acc : a:Fn(val) ? val : v:null}, v:null)
endfunction
```

Comment: To call the function: `let commit = FindItem(state.commits, {item -> StartsWith(parent_commit, item.short_commit_hash)})`

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I've found (in execution time) was to filter everything and check the first item if not empty. This is because loops are really slow

```
:echo filter(copy(state.commits), predicate)[0]
```

When I need the index, I use map + index

```
:echo index(map(copy(state.commits), 'predicate ? 1 : 0'), 1)
```